# Clicking on Django debug toolbar tabs results in 404 Not Found error

Tags: django-debug-toolbar

I am trying to analyze and optimize my sql queries in my Django 1.10 project, and for this reason trying to setup [Django Debug Toolbar](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). For now, I can see the toolbar appear on the left side of my browser, but when I click the tabs, I end up with 404 error.[image]

> GET
>   [http://127.0.0.1:8000/**debug**/render_panel/?store_id=10d77fee31c2425aafb5a2cd7898111f&panel_id=SQLPanel](http://127.0.0.1:8000/__debug__/render_panel/?store_id=10d77fee31c2425aafb5a2cd7898111f&panel_id=SQLPanel)
>   404 (Not Found)

My URLConf file:

```
urlpatterns = []
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = (url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),)

urlpatterns += (
    url(r'', include('my_project_urls.urls')),
    # ...
)
```

settings.py (only relevant content):

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'android_blend.urls'
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static-only")
#STATIC_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static-only")]
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","media")
#MEDIA_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media")]
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"),
    )

def show_toolbar(request):
    if not request.is_ajax() and request.user and request.user.id == 4:
        return True
    return False

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': 'android_blend.settings.show_toolbar'}
```

I blame the error on an erroneous settings regarding static files. In the cmd, when I navigate to the project root folder and run `python manage.py collectstatic`, I see a folder named `static` appear on my Desktop, instead of project root. I manually copied the `static-only` folder which was in the newly created `static` folder into the static folder of my project root, but again no success. Could anyone help me with finding the solution ? Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you already found it but there has been a breaking change which was "announced" here:

https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/issues/954

and documented here:

https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/pull/961/commits/22c22d719e856045e76b399d4e4ab5dc5e3fc040

> For versions < 1.8, the callback should also return False for AJAX requests. Since version 1.8, AJAX requests are checked in the middleware, not the callback. This allows reusing the callback to verify access to panel views requested via AJAX.

So your code should be fine like this:

```
def show_toolbar(request):
if request.user and request.user.id == 4:
    return True
return False
```

Comment: I've did an upgrade for djdt 1.5 -> 1.9.1 and this was the problem: the callback.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I put the `__debug__` URL above the static and media routes and then it works.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns.append(path('__debug__/', include('debug_toolbar.urls')))
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

From a recent django-debug-toolbar version (1.9.1), I've downgraded to an older one (1.6) and I'm no longer getting a 404.

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting 404s for all, But after rearranging the MIDDLEWARE `debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware` higher as much as possible, My problem is solved.
Just keep in mind that The order of MIDDLEWARE is important. You should include the Debug Toolbar middleware as early as possible in the list, which is also mentioned in the documents. [Add the Middleware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSQ5N.png)